# JavaScript compare an array to an object of arrays to see if their values match

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array that I'm trying to compare to see if the values in array 1 are in any of the arrays inside an object:

```
arr1 = [9]

obj1 = {Cards: [8,5], Loans: [], Shares: [0,9,25]}
```

I'm using JavaScript(ECMAScript 5) to try and do this, all I need is `true` to be returned if any of the values in `arr1` are found inside `obj1`.

What I've tried:

```
function arraysEqual(_arr1, _arr2) {
  if (!Array.isArray(_arr1) || !Array.isArray(_arr2) || _arr1.length !== _arr2.length)
    return false;
  var arr1 = _arr1.concat().sort();
  var arr2 = _arr2.concat().sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This however will just test to see if the arrays in specific so I have to call this three times to check the values, even this however will return `false` when I try:

```
arraysEqual(arr1, obj1.Shares)
```

Would like this to be done with one call

Comment: what code have you tried? where did you have problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) item in `arr1` is in arr2 using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.every(function(n){
    return arr2.indexOf(n) > -1
  })
}

var arr = [9],
    obj = { Cards: [8,5], Loans: [], Shares: [0,9,25] }

console.log(compare(arr, obj.Shares))
console.log(compare(arr, obj.Cards))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for...in loop to iterate through the object, then you can use a for loop to iterate through the main array, finally using an array.includes on your secondary array (from the object) to see if any elements from the main array exist in the secondary array

```js
arr1 = [3]
obj1 = {Cards: [8,5], Loans: [], Shares: [0,9,25]};

for (arr2 in obj1)
{
  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (obj1[arr2].includes(arr1[i]))
    {
      console.log('exists');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing is using Array.prototype.some(),

```js
var array = [8,9];
var obj = {o1:[18,99], o2:[19], o3:[8,56]};
var p = array.some((arr) => {
    var ret =  Object.values(obj).find((value) => {
        return value.find((val) => val === arr);
    });
    return ret ? true : false;

});

console.log(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```js
let arr1 = [9, 8]

let obj1 = {Cards: [8,5], Loans: [], Shares: [0,9,25]}

function check(arr1, obj1) {
  let values = Object.keys(obj1).map((key)=> obj1[key]).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val));

   for(let n of arr1) {
        if(values.indexOf(n) === -1) return false;
      }
   return true;
}
  
console.log(check(arr1, obj1));
```

Comment: cant use ES6 with this solution

Comment: this one should be ES5 compatible

Comment: @PaulBota Object.values didn't exist in ES5.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk yea you are right, updated it. thank you